# How to fit dynamic data into A4 sized html page

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I have been stuck on this issue for a very long time and I am trying to find out the best way to modify my code.
I am using handlebars to display user input data which could range from 1 paragraph to n number of lines in a pdf report.
The pdf report is generated with puppeteer which converts HTML generated by handlebars into different a4 sized pages. The CSS has a   tag which has the dimensions of the a4 size page.
Currently, I am putting all data into one  tag and closing it. But when the data is too less, the page looks blank and when the data is too big it just spills and looks hidden to the user.
I have attached the CSS code which has the page-break.

There are three to four user inputs like this and I want all of them to flow together and look continuous.

My js code inside handlebars helper currently looks like this for one of the input:

```
      i = 0;
        let myLines = inputData
            .split(" ")
            .splice(i, 15)
            .join(" ");
        Page += `<section class="sheet"> <main class="main main--lg main--top"><p><h2 class="main__title color-primary">User Input</h2><p>`;
        while (inputData) {
            if (i != 0 && i % 600 == 0) {
                Page += `</section><section class="sheet"> <main class="main main--lg main--top"><p>`;
            }
            Page += `<span class = "break-line">${myLines} </span>`;
            i = i + 15;
            myLines = userData
                .split(" ")
                .splice(i, 15)
                .join(" ");
        }
        Page += `</section>`;
    }
```

CSS of section which is getting called to add page-breaks:

```
.sheet {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    page-break-after: always;
}

body.A4 .sheet {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
}

@media screen {
    body {
        background: #e0e0e0;
    }
    .sheet {
        background: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.5mm 2mm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0.5mm 2mm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 5mm;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  It sounds like you're having a CSS problem, but you're showing us your JavaScript.  Is the output HTML what you want?  If so, narrow down the problem to that and the CSS and give us an example we can reproduce.

Comment: Hey Brad, I have added the CSS to the question. The output I want is html which will then be converted into pdf by puppeteer. All I am looking for is a method to arrange all this data in A4 pdf sheets(refer CSS) and was looking for a way to do this via js and css. I hope you a better idea now.